# How to use Linq to select and group complex child object from a parents list

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

How to use Linq to select and group complex child object from a parents list.

I have an **OrderList** each of order object has a **OrderProductVariantList**(OrderLineList), and each of **OrderProductVariant** object has ProductVariant, and then the **ProductVariant**  object will have a **Product** object which contains product information.

**My goal is to select and group the most popular products from the order list.**

Can anyone help me with this?

Many thanks.

Comment: repost from earlier today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613384/how-to-use-linq-to-select-and-group-complex-child-object-from-a-parents-list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your description is hard to follow, but I think you just want to get out the Products and rank them by the number of times they occur.  SelectMany will be helpful for this.

```
 var query = orderList.SelectMany( o => o.OrderLineList )
                        // results in IEnumerable<OrderProductVariant>
                      .Select( opv => opv.ProductVariant )
                      .Select( pv => p.Product )
                      .GroupBy( p => p )
                      .Select( g => new {
                                    Product = g.Key,
                                    Count = g.Count()
                       });
```

Comment: Try breaking it down into each component of the query.  And see what each one gives you, e.g. `var q = orderList.SelectMany();` then `var q1 = q.Select(...)`, etc.  I'm not sure why it wouldn't show up in the debugger -- are you looking at the local variables?

Comment: HI tvanfosson, thank you very much. The Linq is really good tool. I have managed to get the result. Here is another question, in the OrderProductVariant(orderLine) object I have the Quantity and UnitPrice properties, if also want to bring them into the report how can I do that?

Comment: Instead of selecting just the project, select a new anonymous type that includes the Product, Quantity, and UnitPrice.  You'll have to use all three as the key for grouping -- again, use an anonymous object for this, then select each out a g.Key.Product, g.Key.Quantity, ...

Answer (score 1):

A query is not a result. To view the result you can iterate over the `query` object:

```
foreach (var result in query) {
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

As to why query wasn't available in the watch window, I can only imagine that it either wasn't in scope yet, or it had already gone out of scope. Try putting a breakpoint on the line immediately after the line you posted where you assign to query.

Comment: Hmm.. the question is now completely different from when I posted this answer. The original question was something like `For this query: "var query = orderList.SelectMany(...blah" why is there no result, and why does it say "query is not defined" in the watch window?`

Comment: Hi Mark, I do not why the data not showing in the watch window, but it can bring the result out, very strange.